# Why does NdisFSendNetBufferLists only work when called from FilterSendNetBufferLists?

Tags: windows, driver, wdk, windows-kernel, ndis

I have got an NDIS Filter Driver (see https://pastebin.com/c5r87NNw) and a userspace application.

I want to send an arbitrary packet with my filter driver (in the function `SendData`). I can see with a DbgPrint in the function `FilterReceiveNetBufferLists` that I have received the packet but I can not find the packet in *WireShark*.

As long as the code from `SendData` was called or directly pasted in the `FilterSendNetBufferLists`-function, it worked just fine. But now, as the execution of `SendData` is triggered by the userspace application, it doesn't work anymore.

Do you have any guess why that might be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made it work: The error was in my `OriginalNdisFilterHandle`. I set it in the function `FilterAttach` and didn't think that the function gets called multiple times. Because of this the variable had the wrong value.

Answer (score 4):

Wireshark is an interesting thing, because it isn't necessarily telling you the exact truth.  If possible, I suggest running Wireshark on another PC, which will give you a cleaner perspective on what actually got put onto the wire.  (For the purest perspective: disable the other PC's hardware offloads, especially RSC, so the other PC's NIC isn't munging the packets before you can capture them.)

Older versions of Wireshark have an NDIS5 protocol driver named NPF.  This guy sits *above* all the filter drivers, so he wouldn't ordinarily see any of the Tx traffic.  But as a special concession to this situation, NDIS will loop back the Tx path back onto the Rx path (with the `NDIS_NBL_FLAGS_IS_LOOPBACK_PACKET` flag set), so old drivers like NPF can see a copy of the Tx packet in their Rx path.

Recently, the npcap project converted the old NPF driver to an NDIS6 LWF named [NPCAP](https://github.com/nmap/npcap/tree/master/packetWin7/npf/npf).  This driver is much better, for a number of reasons, but one thing to keep in mind is that, as a filter driver, it sits somewhere in the filter stack.  If it sits above your LWF, then it won't see any packets you transmit (or modify).

Check with !ndiskd.miniport to see what wireshark looks like on your machine: is it a protocol named NPF, or is there a filter driver named NPCAP.  If the latter, is it above or below your filter driver?

Anyway, all that is to say that you can't completely trust wireshark on the same box as the drivers you're testing.  It's better and easier to do packet capture on a separate machine.

As for your code, make sure that your FilterSendNetBufferListsComplete handler is looking though all the NBLs and removing ones whose NET_BUFFER_LIST::SourceHandle is equal to your `OriginalNdisFilterHandle`.  Those should be freed back to NdisFreeNetBufferList (or cached for later reuse, but NDIS does a decent job of caching already).  You may already have that code, and it just didn't make it onto pastebin.

I don't see anything that would cause the Tx to always fail.  You do need to track the pause state of the filter, and prevent (or queue) Tx operations while paused.  So your SendData function could be written like this:

```
NTSTATUS SendData(MY_FILTER *filter) {
    if (!ExAcquireRundownProtection(&filter->PauseRundown)) {
        return STATUS_NDIS_PAUSED;
    }

    . . . allocate and send NBL . . .;

    return STATUS_SUCCESS;
}

void FilterSendNetBufferListsComplete(MY_FILTER *filter, NET_BUFFER_LIST *nblChain) {
    for (auto nbl = nblChain; nbl; nbl = nbl->Next) {
        if (nbl->SourceHandle == filter->NdisHandle) {
            . . . detach NBL from chain . . .;
            . . . free NBL back to NDIS . . .;
            ExReleaseRundownProtection(&filter->PauseRundown);
        }
    }
}

void FilterPause(MY_FILTER *filter) {
    ExWaitForRundownProtectionRelease(&filter->PauseRundown);
}

void FilterRestart(MY_FILTER *filter) {
    ExReInitializeRundownProtection(&filter->PauseRundown);
}
```

If you get that wrong, then sometimes NDIS will crash when you send a packet.  Some packets will also quietly fail to transmit, if you are unlucky enough to send them while the datapath is paused.  (Fixing this won't magically cause packets to always succeed to transmit -- it'll just mean that it won't be quiet anymore: you'll see STATUS_NDIS_PAUSED when trying to send a packet when the NIC isn't ready yet.)

Comment: I added the RundownProtection in my code and in the function `SendData` it didn't return STATUS_NDIS_PAUSED. So it's clear that it is not paused. 
I also looked up the position of my Filter Driver and it turned out that it is the topmost filter driver. My WireShark already uses NPCAP.
I already have freed my NBLs in the function `FilterSendNetBufferListsComplete`.

Comment: I made it work: The error was in my `OriginalNdisFilterHandle`. I set it in the function `FilterAttach` and didn't think that the function gets called multiple times. Because of this the variable had the wrong value.
Thank you for your help!

Comment: Great, glad it's working.  Agreed with your analysis - you tend to not have much global state in a LWF (except maybe an NBL pool and a control device).